# Is there a way to check whether the data buffer for a socket is empty or not in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I want to verify if the socket data buffer is empty or not before calling `socket.recv(bufsize[, flags])`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to make your socket non-blocking:

```
socket.setblocking(0)
```

After that call, if you read from a socket without available data it will not block, but instead an exception is raised. See [socket.setblocking(flag)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking) for details.

---

For more advanced uses, you might look at [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html). Something like:

```
r, _, _ = select([socket],[],[],0)
#                               ^
#           Timeout of 0 to poll (and not block)
```

Will inform you if some data are available to *read* in your socket.

Answer (score 8):

You can peek (look without actually consuming the data):

```
data = conn.recv(bufsize, socket.MSG_PEEK)
```

Comment: +1 for that option I didn't know :/ According to the man _"`MSG_PEEK`: [...] if the operation would block, the call fails with the error `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`"_ How will behave Python? Throw an exception?

Comment: `socket.error` I would guess, but i'll try to test later! Anyway I'm assuming the OP is already non-blocking, otherwise I don't see the point :)

Comment: Yes, this is simple solution compared to select()/poll() in this particular case.
I did not know this.
Plus, we may need to make the socket non blocking too, otherwise,
peeking blocks, which is not we want generally.

Comment: This is a blocking call for anyone curious. Here is the documentation on `MSG_PEEK`: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/recv.html