# How to find out how many bytes in socket before recv in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, recv

I have a TCP handling streams of data. It takes 4096 bytes at a time, but I need a way to find out the whole socket size before it recv. This is so I can determine how many times the socket will be read before it switches socket. It will also notify that this is the last recv of this socket so that I can do something with it before select switches to the other socket when it becomes available.

```
def handle_tcp(self, sock, remote):  
    fdset = [sock, remote]  
    while True:  
        r, w, e = select.select(fdset, [], [])  
        # How to find out how much bytes need to be read from socket?
        if sock in r:  
            non_blocking_calculation()
            if remote.send(sock.recv(4096)) <= 0: break  
        if remote in r: 
            non_blocking_calculation() 
            if sock.send(remote.recv(4096)) <= 0: break
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'capturing the last send'? Do you want to keep the last data sent? The last amount of bytes sent? Hope you can clarify it a little bit!

Comment: @Rezniaq I do not want to keep it, I just want to be notified that this is the last recv() of this socket, so then I can have another function process it. Then go back to select to switch to the other socket if need be. I will correct it now

Comment: @Rezniaq e.g. after `select()`, (ceiling(sizeofwholesocket / 4096)) will determine how many times it will send

Comment: I think that by 'size of whole socket' you want to know how many bytes are queued to be read, am i right? If so, i guess you can do

`sock.recv(1, socket.MSG_PEEK)`.

I do not code on Python, but searching through Google took me to that line. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Why can't you just read until EOF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You beated me to it. In accordance with Igor Kalinosvkiy way. You can either Use **FIONREAD** to do this or use **MSG_PEEK** and keep reading until empty. For example, after `select()`.

```
import fcntl, termios, array, math
...
sock_size = array.array('i', [0])  # initialise outside While loop
if sock in r:
    fcntl.ioctl(sock, termios.FIONREAD, sock_size)
    count = ceil(sock_size[0] / float(BUF_SIZE))
    print("Socket size: {} and count: {}".format(sock_size[0], count)
```

Comment: An example of `MSG_PEEK`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25435394/4368898

Answer (score 2):

[Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp) and [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736550(v=vs.85).aspx) have **FIONREAD**(synonym **SIOCINQ**) ioctl for that.

Python has limited ioctl's support in **socket** and **fcntl** modules but in usual TCP programming such ioctl's are not widely used. Usually you just **setblocking**(*false*) and read all available data until BlockingIOError raises. Ore define some kind of messages with headers/markers specifying size/bounds.