# Python socket.recv() is waiting and don't read data while data is flowing

Tags: python, sockets, barcode-scanner, recv

I'm using python for reading barcode code numbers. At first everything is ok. But after a while (I don't know the exact time) socket.recv doesn't get the data from barcode reader. When I restart the program everything works fine again. I put counter for reset socket connection and also put timer again for reset connection but it didn't work. I've been trying to solve this for weeks. Does anybody know this problem. You can find my recv codes below :

```
def getBarcodeValue(client_socket):
print("Waiting to reading...")

data = ""

r, _, _ = select.select([client_socket], [], [])
if r:
    try:
        # ready to receive

        data = client_socket.recv(1024)  # most 1024 bytes can be read.
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        return data
        # print("Data :", realData)

        # print("Byte size", len(realData))
        # print("Data type :", type(realData))
    except socket.timeout as e:
        err = e.args[0]
        if err == errno.EAGAIN or err == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            sleep(1)
            print('No data available')
        else:
            # a "real" error occurred
            print(e)
            # sys.exit(1)
            print("Data receive error")
    except socket.error as e:
        # Something else happened, handle error, exit, etc.
        print(e)
        print("socket.error")
```

After a while program  prints "waiting to reading" and it waits until forever.

Edit1 : Program doesn't throw any error. It just waits until forever after printed the "waiting to reading" string. At first everything is ok. While products is flowing conveyor also barcode reader is reading barcodes and give output.However, socket.recv() doesn't get data after a while.

Comment: After an error you may want to reconnect to the socket, which the code you shown (where you pass in the socket) doesn't do.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error. just waiting after printed the "waiting to reading" string

Comment: `recv`is a command that may block until data is received (=forever is nothing arrives) if your socket it set to blocking. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736204/how-to-find-out-how-many-bytes-in-socket-before-recv-in-python#44738508
the right strategy depends on the operating system. 
it's also possible that your scanner wants some kind of return from you after you receive something.

Comment: You only show a small part that can block if there is nothing more to read from the socket. To make it look like a [mre] (what we **actually need** in order to help you), we need a little more for example is that code called from a loop.