# Python single socket accept multiple different protocols

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I am trying to build a client/server program and my plan is to have the server listen on a single socket. Then my clients will connect to it using either HTTP, HTTPS, TLS.

My end goal is to be able to listen on a single socket. When I get a new connection, I want to be able to know if it is TLS or not.

Looking at the code for TLS sockets, it looks like I need to wrap the connection in TLS code before calling recv().

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4444))

sock.listen(1)

conn, addr = sock.accept()

print(conn)
print(addr)
```

This is my code I am using for testing. When I print both conn and addr they look the same when I try to connect using non-ssl and ssl connection. I used nc for non-ssl and ncat for ssl.

Is it possible to do this? I know the alternative is to use another port but wanted to see if I could do it like this.

Comment: This is at best very tricky and painful, at worst it is nearly impossible. The difficulty is that you need to *peek* at the first few bytes of a TCP connection without consuming them. You can use  the `socket.MSG_PEEK` option to `socket.recv()` to accomplish this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25435394/238704) answer. Then, based on your examination of these first few bytes, you can (maybe) determine what kind of connection the client is trying to make. If you decide it is TLS/SSL you can then wrap the socket with `SSLContext.wrap_socket()`.

Comment: *"Then my clients will connect to it using either HTTP, HTTPS, TLS."* - HTTPS is a protocol on top of TLS. While you can distinguish plain HTTP from TLS based on peeking the first few bytes as James recommended, you cannot distinguish between HTTPS (TLS+HTTP) and "TLS" (TLS+something which is not HTTP) this way. You have to decide after TLS handshake what the inner protocol is.

Comment: This looks promising. Seems like it is used here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/37242/socket.MSG_PEEK